# JQuery table w/ sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are all kinds of JQuery widgets that offer some nice features like sorting by a columns (like http://tablesorter.com/docs/ or http://www.datatables.net/)

I haven't found one that integrates with server side sorting though.  I have the following requirements:

1. sort by clicked column (server side sort)
2. filter by a text field over each column
3. selectable which columns to display

any suggestions on a widget that has some or all of these criteria?

thanks

Comment: what is your intent to sort by server side? that would cause a refresh which is why people choose to use client side sorting like tablesorter?

Comment: because there could be 10000s of records, too many to return to the client.

Comment: just found this, has promise
http://datatables.net/1.5-beta/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Sounds like you want "pagination" then, not "sorting".

Comment: need pagination too.  but definitely sorting.  clicking on a column should sort by that column (server side request)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would prefer to roll my own in this situation.  Filtering is especially easy using jQuery: `$('tr > td.columnName').each(...)`; just set the `display` style of the row to `none` if it doesn't match, `block` otherwise.  Hiding columns can be done in a similar manner.  Sorting isn't too bad--though notably more complicated.  You need to sort (which can take a while, depending on your algorithm) and then place the rows into the table in the order you determined.

Alternatively, find a plug-in that has sorting accomplished, but also generates simple markup, so you can extend it with your own filtering.

Answer (score 0):

As a step up from rolling your own (which is not a bad suggestion, BTW), try this jQuery plugin out: [Ingrid](http://www.reconstrukt.com/ingrid/).  The descriptions of the code talk about using server side data generation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tiny Table](http://www.leigeber.com/2009/03/table-sorter/).
It does not require jQuery but you put a wrapper around it.

[http://www.leigeber.com/2009/03/table-sorter http://www.leigeber.com/2009/03/table-sorter](http://www.leigeber.com/2009/03/table-sorter)

[image]
<sub>(source: [leigeber.com](http://www.leigeber.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/tiny-table.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think [DisplayTag](http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-sorting.jsp) is your solution. It was used to display data for servlets, portlets and it supports a lot of functions like paging, sorting on server side.